Position a responsive circle in the top-right corner of the screen
I want to draw a circle in the top-right corner. I'm having a hard time making it responsive. I tried this code , but nothing seems to work.
This code is causing horizontal scrolling in the responsive design.
knowing : The circle should be quartered; only one-quarter of it should be displayed in the corner.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.circle {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle top-right"></div>
</div>




Make it simple:


.circle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: min(25vw,500px); /* the size */
  background: red; /* the color */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}
<div class="circle top-right"></div>




position:fixed allows to give a top and right property.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.circle {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right:25vw;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle top-right"></div>
</div>



Hope this is what you imagined.
